# How to use temporary variable in Update query?

Tags: mysql

How can I set a variable while doing an Update statement?

I can't seem to figure out the syntax. I am using this `@tp` variable for holding calculated result and it will be used in `when` condition.

I want something like this:

```
UPDATE users IU
INNER JOIN activity_stats DAS
    ON (IU.user_id=DAS.for_user_id) SET 
    @tp:= IU.total_subscription_time - (unix_timestamp()- IU.start_date),
    IU.time_period_left = CASE WHEN @tp > 0 THEN @tp ELSE 0 END,
    IU.used_time = (unix_timestamp() - IU.start_date),
    IU.status = CASE WHEN @tp > 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END,
    DAS.total_time_used = DAS.total_time_used + IU.used_time 
WHERE IU.time_period_left > 0
  AND IU.status='A'
```

but it's saying the syntax is wrong:
[image: but it's saying the syntax is wrong]

Comment: Maybe, if you can explain what are you try to doing with some table reference, you can make this work without an `user-defined variable`. The first mistake is the `,` after `ON (IU.user_id=DAS.for_user_id)`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html), the `SET` clause expects a list of *column* assignments, meaning that the left side of each assignment must be a column reference, not a variable reference.

However, you can use variable assignment in the right hand side, where an expression goes, for instance like this:

```
IU.used_time = (@usedtime := unix_timestamp() - IU.start_date),
```

In the line above, the result of `unix_timestamp() - IU.start_date` is assigned to `@usedtime`, then the entire variable assignment expression evaluates to the same value, which is eventually stored into the `IU.used_time` column.

The variable assigned this way can then be used in other expressions that follow. Your update statement, therefore, could be rewritten e.g. like this:

```
UPDATE
    users IU
    INNER JOIN activity_stats DAS
        ON (IU.user_id=DAS.for_user_id)
SET 
    IU.used_time        = (@usedtime := unix_timestamp() - IU.start_date),
    IU.time_period_left = CASE WHEN (@timeleft := IU.total_subscription_time - @usedtime) > 0 THEN @timeleft ELSE 0 END,
    IU.status           = CASE WHEN @timeleft > 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END,
    DAS.total_time_used = DAS.total_time_used + @usedtime
WHERE
    IU.time_period_left > 0
    AND IU.status='A'
;
```

Note that, in addition to fixing the syntax in general, I have moved the `IU.used_time` column assignment to the top, so that the result of `unix_timestamp() - IU.start_date` could be re-used in the expression for `@timeleft`. You can keep your order of assignments, of course. Note, however, that `IU.used_time` in the last assignment

```
DAS.total_time_used = DAS.total_time_used + IU.used_time
```

may still hold the old value. So, even if you decide to keep the order of assignments, I would still recommend that you use an expression rather than a column reference there if you want to use an *updated* value in that assignment.

See a live demo of this syntax at *[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=bc80de9bb13724cc85011ad58a2795b4)*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Andriy M , I clearly understood that how to use temp variable in expression evaluation and use that temp variable value in another expression. Finally i modified my query as below and achieved my objective.

```
UPDATE users IU
   INNER JOIN activity_stats DAS ON (IU.user_id=DAS.for_user_id) SET
   IU.time_period_left = CASE WHEN (@tp:= IU.total_subscription_time - (unix_timestamp()- IU.start_date)) > 0 THEN @tp ELSE 0 END,
   IU.used_time = (unix_timestamp() - IU.start_date),
   IU.status = CASE WHEN @tp > 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END,
   DAS.total_time_used = DAS.total_time_used + IU.used_time 
WHERE IU.time_period_left > 0 AND IU.status='A'
```